# Undefined when selecting button in Puppeteer

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

Why do I get `undefined` when I run  `console.log(result);` ?
How can I fix it?

```
const express = require('express');
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const app = express();


(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless:false, devtools: true});
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://my.gumtree.com/login', {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});
  await page.waitFor(4000);

// await page.waitForSelector('button[id="google-sign-in-button"]');
// await page.click('id[name="google-sign-in-button"]');


   const result = await page.evaluate(x => {
    return Promise.resolve(document.getElementById('google-sign-in-button'));
  }, 7);
  
console.log(result);
 

//await browser.close();
})();


app.listen(3000, function (){
    console.log('server started');
})
```

`<button type="submit" id="google-sign-in-button" class="btn-icn-left btn-secondary btn-full-width btn-google-icon" data-social-login="type:googleplus,appId:67555700125-lvoarr4qau5lkhuks3bn3bl9u3bmmfuf.apps.googleusercontent.com" data-analytics="gaEvent:LoginAttempt,userData:{lip:Google}" data-q="google-sign-in-button">Sign in with Google</button>`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, `page.evaluate()` can only transfer serializable values (roughly, the values JSON can handle). `document.getElementById()` returns DOM elements that are not serializable (they contain methods and circular references). Unserializable data is usualy replaced with empty object or `undefined`. You need to either return serializable value or use something like `page.$(selector)` and [`ElementHandle` API](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#class-elementhandle).

Comment: How can I return a serializable object so that I  can click on it?

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot. Serializable data is for... data) If you need an element to click on, use `page.$(selector)` and other functions that return ElementHandle. ElementHandle has `.click()` method. Or you can click inside browser context in  `page.evaluate()`.

Answer (score 1):

- It is not necessary to wrap with `Promise.resolve` returning value from `evaluate` callback function.
- Try to return a plain object or primitive value (serializable) from `evaluate`.

```js
const result = await page.evaluate(x => {
  const el = document.getElementById('google-sign-in-button')
  const buttonContent = el.textContent
  return buttonContent
}, 7);
```

To click on button, you need to use `page.click` method instead of `page.evaluate`:

```js
await page.click("#google-sign-in-button");
```

You cannot operate on DOM element outside of `page.evaluate` callback function, because the callback function called in "browser's" context and then returned value processed in Node.js code without any knowledge about DOM at all.

Comment: and how do I click on the button?

Comment: Ok, but I don't need the content of the button, I need the button so that I can  click on it. How could I do this?

Comment: To click on button, you need to use `page.click` method:
`await page.click("#google-sign-in-button'");`

Answer (score 0):

```
(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless:false, devtools: true});
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://my.gumtree.com/login', {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});
  await page.waitFor(4000);


//get the selector by its id
const myButton = await page.$('#google-sign-in-button');
myButton.click();


//await browser.close();
})();


app.listen(3000, function (){
    console.log('server started');
})
```